# .NET C# WinForms exam for trading company

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading, observer-pattern, trading

tomorrow I'm doing an exam for a .NET development role in a trading company. The type of skills they are looking for are WinForms, multi-threading, delegates, events, etc. I'm more of an ASP.NET / middle tier / database developer but have done some WinForms in the past. I'm interested in the role as it's a foot in the door to trading software so I'd take the role if offered.

I've had unsuccessful interviews in the past for similar roles, and they seem to look for the same thing i.e they ask about the Observer pattern, multi threading, and event creation and invocation, all of which I've been reading up on.

Are there any sample projects or code out there that a typical trading system / platform would use? I feel like I'm missing something that all these systems use i.e. some design pattern or methodology that's common to this type of application.

**EDIT**

Ok so to put it a different way, could/would a typical trading system be a set of forms that need to be updated when a certain event happens? E.g. say we have a collection of objects and the collection has events that fire when the collection is updated, would all the forms subscribe to those events in order to be notified of the update? Would this be a possible scenario for a trading system?

Supposing there are multiple users in an organisation all using the same WinForms app and some centralised object gets updated, is it possible to notify multiple remote WinForms apps of this update, or for the apps to subscribe to events on a remote object?

Comment: It looks like you have answered your own question.  You need to read up on WinForms, multi-threading, delegates, events and the observer pattern. etc

Comment: Hi @David thanks, I have been reading up on all that but I need something to apply it to. I'd love to find some sample code or a simple trading type project to see how it all hangs together.

Answer (score 0):

In the multiple users scenario that you describe, there would be no "centralized object". An object is a construct within the boundary of a process, and each user would have their own instance of the WinForms app, its own process on each user's machine.

A more likely setup for what you describe would be a WinForms app that connects to a backend server component, i.e. via WCF. The server could then send push notifications to each connected/subscribed client when something of significance is updated.